# One object darker than another

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

I have two separate objects, however one seems darker than the other. I've checked the normals, which seem to be all pointing outwards

Could someone please explain why the smaller object seems darker than the larger one in 3d view?

[image]

Comment: The "Normals" are probably inverted. In "Edit Mode" select all and "Recalculate Normals".

Comment: Did you add materials to not selected object?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the color of meshes in viewport and their meaning [image]

Comment: @MartinZ Answer was revised, consider revoting?

Comment: Yep, I'll gladly upvote that. :)